# Stand alone screen recorder for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, screen-recorder

I am looking for a free **stand alone** (i.e. no installation required) program to record the screen in Windows 7 (64 bit). I know about

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/magazine/2009.03.utilityspotlight2.aspx

but I am not sure that I trust the file that is downloaded (It is supposed to be 10 MB, but the file is actually 22 MB)

I also know that one can use VLC, but here it doesn't record the cursor.

Edit: I do not have a video camera.

Comment: VurusTotal says it's clean: https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/d5d9dc1abf15342f95437dc1899ed5475e6561a9064c7ff405d0d74e528e20d3/analysis/ also the file was digitally signed. I would say it's legit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CamStudio is a screen recording program, and there's a portable version here: http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/camstudio_portable ?

Answer (score 1):

[My Screen Capture](http://www.myportablesoftware.com/myscreencapture.aspx) is a simple and little software which help.

Comment: Too bad it only takes screenshots.